# Cannot read property 'classList' of null как исправить ошибку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form")
const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName")
const lastName = document.getElementById("lastName")
const email = document.getElementById("email")

if (form) {
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    checkInputs();
  })

  function checkInputs() {
    const firstNameValue = firstName.value.trim()
    const lastNameValue = lastName.value.trim()
    const emaiValue = email.value.trim()

    // check firstName
    if (firstNameValue === "") {
      setErrorFor(firstName, "First name cannot be blank")
    }
    else {
      setSuccessFor(firstName)
    }

    // check lastName
    if (lastNameValue === "") {
      setErrorFor(lastName, "Last name cannot be blank")
    }
    else {
      setSuccessFor(lastName)
    }

    // check email
    if (emaiValue === "") {
      setErrorFor(email, "Email cannot be blank")
    }
    else if (!isEmail(emaiValue)) {
      setErrorFor(email, "Email is not valid")
    }
    else {
      setSuccessFor(email)
    }

  } 

  // setErrorFor
  function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formGroup = input.parentNode
    const small = formGroup.querySelector(".error__text")

    small.innerText = message;

    formGroup.classList.add("error")
  }

  // setSuccessFor
  function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formGroup = input.parentNode

    formGroup.classList.remove("error")
    formGroup.classList.add("success")
  }

  // isEmail
  function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="№" class="contact__form" id="form">
  <div class="contact__form--group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="firstName">
    <small class="error__text">Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="contact__form--group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lastName">
    <small class="error__text">Error message!</small>
  </div>
  <div class="contact__form--group contact__form--group-last">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    <small class="error__text">Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="contact__form--textarea">
    <textarea name="area" rows="15"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Поясните в каком случае ошибка возникает. При проверке формы вроде всё нормально.

Comment: Когда нажимаю на инпут с емейлом возникает такая ошибка

Comment: А в документе случайно не завалялся еще такой `id=email`? `querySelector` возвратит `null`, когда нет такого класса. Может не тот элемент нашелся.

Comment: нужно перебирать или просто другой id присвоить?

Comment: У меня был вопрос, есть такой `id` или нет. Это важно.

Comment: Да есть, нашел, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Во первых избавится от всех `id` - это уникальный идентификатор! Их не может быть несколько - это ошибка. Если уже и использовать `id`, значит только для значимых блоков. А элементы внутри можно найти и без `id`. Для `email` это может быть так `form.querySelector('input[type="email"]')`

Comment: Щас попробую, спасибо

Comment: огромное спасибо, чет туплю сильно